# How can I redirect a user back to signout page when timed out? Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have site that users lots of ajax(jquery). Now if the user times out for whatever reason(walked about for 30mins or something). On there next action I want them to be returned to the login page.

I setup everything in the webconfig(returnUrl and timeout) and if they try to go to a page they have no premission to go to they get sent to the login page.

However I have the authorize tags on the methods in my controllers that are used for ajax requests. So if a user timesout they are no longer authenticated but they might be on that needed authentication since they logged in and walked away.

Now they could go and try to save something at this point that would do an ajax request. The authorize tag will stop them from doing this since they will fail authorization and the return url will kick in.

However eventhough the return url seems to be sent back to them they are not redirected to the signin page. So I am guessing since all this stuff is ajax thats why it is not working properly. So is there away I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the Ajax error for a 403 response

Comment: Well actually it seems that I get 200 OK back but if I setup a Jquery Ajax.Error it goes to the error method. But not sure how check if it is 403 error.

Comment: Also if this would work this would only fix half of the problem. Since I have ajax tabs and what happens is if the authentication fails. It loads the signin page into the tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Run a client-side function every 30 seconds using setTimeout, which should ask the server via AJAX if the session has been timed out.  If it has, the client-side code could toss out any login cookie and redirect to the login page.

You can either code hard-code the login url into the client-side code, or have the server handler return the value from the web.config if it needs to timeout.

This still leaves the possibility that the user could try something in the 0-30 seconds between when the user actually times out and the client side code does its request to check.  To prevent this as well, have the server send back the amount of time left in the session, that way your client-side code can make the decision to either check back again sooner, or do the client-side redirect before the server-side drop-dead time.

Comment: Could you write me a short same code. I am not sure how to make it run everything 30seconds nor what setTimeout is. Is this a jquery function? javscript function?

Comment: Hi Chobo, Rasik again....Here is the link for sample code on Auto Logout written by my friend and colleague... take a look at it....

http://www.firozansari.com/2009/05/15/implementing-auto-logout-functionality/

Comment: This could hammer the server if there are more than a few people using it.

Comment: The link provided by Rasik Jain is good, although it is worth noting that it assumes that the client-side is authoritative on when it is time to force logout.  If the server needs to be authoritative, then there could still be a problem if client and server disagree.

Of course, on the server side, you can (and should) always check to see if the login is still valid before doing something as a result of client action.

Comment: I am not sure I follow you David. I am not sure how the client and server could disagree and even if they do disagree I would take whatever the server says since it does check the users credentials every time it hits the server. So could you maybe explain what you mean in more detail? thanks.

Comment: @Rasik Jain, Hey again. I tried your friends script but I am having problems with it.  I set my timeout for 2mins and a warning at 1min but it seems to never work that way. What seems to to happen is like 3 seconds before the auto logout should happen is when you see the 1min warning message. Of course it flies by so that you can see it. 

I think your friends script is good and he probably should make it into a jquery plugin. The only thing that concerns me is this. say a user has no activity for 9mins and logout on server and from the script is 10mins. The user comes back and moves the mouse

Comment: on my webpage resting the client side page. However if he does not do anything in in that one min that hits the server he will be timed out. So that's what concerns me about this way.